# HTTP answer add a number before body

Tags: php, sockets, http

I use PHP sockets for getting HTTP answers from web-servers. I have noticed some strange situation: after headers before the body appears a hex number which changes at different requests. HTTP answer fragment looks like

```
...
Pragma: no-cache
Vary: Accept-Encoding

9f4
<!DOCTYPE html >
...
```

I have no idea about **9f4** line (it is different all time). Such behavior have stream_socket_client and fsockopen functions. cURL answer has no excessive line. What is it could be? *I have no problem with the line elimination but I want to understand its appearance* Thanks forward!

```
$ip = gethostbyname($_REQUEST["adr"]);
//$ssc=stream_socket_client($ip.":80");
$ssc = fsockopen($ip,80);
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: {$_REQUEST["adr"]}\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($ssc,$in);
$tmp="";
while(!feof($ssc)) {
    $tmp.=fread($ssc,1024);
}
$body.='<plaintext>'.$tmp.'</plaintext>';
```

Comment: IMHO it cannot be analyzed without showing your code.

Comment: $ip = gethostbyname($_REQUEST["adr"]);
//$ssc=stream_socket_client($ip.":80");
$ssc = fsockopen($ip,80);
$in = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\n";
$in .= "Host: {$_REQUEST["adr"]}\r\n";
$in .= "Connection: Close\r\n\r\n";
fwrite($ssc,$in);
$tmp="";
while(!feof($ssc)){
 $tmp.=fread($ssc,1024);
}
$body.='<plaintext>'.$tmp.'</plaintext>';

Comment: Thanks, ** Zaboj Campula ** for formatting! I pressed Enter to enter new line but comment was submitted. My rating is not enough for editing my posts after submitting...

Comment: 6 days after... Still there are no answers... Maybe someone has an inexact idea?